# InDesign — Span an anchored text box over 2 parallel columns

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'd like to span an anchored text box over 2 parallel columns. Those are bilingual, i.e. each containing a separate story.

[image: Screenshot]

Attached is a screenshot that shows 2 boxes (containing red text):

1. An anchored box — anchored in the left column, but the text from the right column is not wrapping.
2. A Non-anchored box — now it works fine by wrapping text from both columns, but it's not flowing with the text.

Is it possible at all?

God bless and thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your text wrap options for the anchored object? It looks like it’s set to inline positioning (so it automatically wraps the text in the same story) but has no actual text wrapping set.

Comment: It is set to "wrap around bounding box". I just tested it: when I copy and paste it (so the second iteration becomes unanchored) it works just like the second non-anchored box in the screenshot.

Comment: Anchored objects only wrap content that comes _after_ the paragraph they’re anchored in. Where exactly is the anchor in your image? Is it perhaps just before the E in “Eher sei Gott…”? If so, that explains it. You’ll have to add a paragraph break after the anchor to get it to wrap that paragraph as well.

Comment: As the description says (under 1.), anchored box is anchored in the left column — check out the blue symbol (¥). It's overlapping with the paragraph symbol (¶), though.

Comment: Oh, there it is—couldn’t see it for the paragraph symbol. Ham, that’s odd. Does the right text frame perhaps begin slightly higher on the page than the left one? That would make it before the left one as far as ID is concerned, and I guess anchored objects in the left frame wouldn’t wrap text in the right frame then… pretty much just guessing now, though.

Comment: Only the story in which you have the anchor is affected by text wrap options. It's (unfortunately in your case) how Indesign work! Not much you can do about it... An alternative way would be to use a single frame, with two columns, using this pattern : Gloria - Gloria - Red text - Latin - German - Red text - Latin - German, and so on... But I understand this could be a lot of work if you have a long document that is already set...